# Creating a file from Native c code android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am trying to demux a video in android application using FFMPEG library. Everything is working fine. But when i try to create a file from the c code to write the different streams in file fopen returns NULL. I can't proceed after that. My code is

```
int ret , got_frame;
av_register_all();
LOGE("Registered formats");
err = av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, "file:/mnt/sdcard/input.mp4", NULL, 0, NULL);
LOGE("Called open file");
if(err!=0) {
    LOGE("Couldn't open file");
    return;
}
LOGE("Opened file");

if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0) {
    LOGE("Unable to get stream info");
    return;
}

videoStream = -1;
audioStream = -1;
for (i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        videoStream = i;
        if(audioStream != -1)
        break;
    }

    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                audioStream = i;
                if(videoStream != -1)
                break;
            }

}
if(videoStream==-1) {
    LOGE("Unable to find video stream");
    return;
}
if(audioStream==-1) {
      LOGE("Unable to find audio stream");
      return;
  }

LOGI("Video stream is [%d] Audio stream [%d]", videoStream,audioStream);

pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

pCodecCtxAudio=pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;

LOGI("Video size is [%d x %d]", pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

videoOut = fopen("file:/mnt/sdcard/videoout.mp4","wb");
if (videoOut == NULL) {
    LOGE("Unable to open output video");
    return;
   }
```

What is the problem with my code. I enabled permissions for the application to write in external storage. Also the path i specified is also correct. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
videoOut = fopen("file:/mnt/sdcard/videoout.mp4","wb");
```

The `fopen()` call takes a filename, not a URI.  Remove the `file:` part.  (Unless you actually want to open a relative path, for which the first component is a directory named "file:".)

It's also a good idea to log the value of `errno` after a failure.

Comment: Though you really should not hardcode paths like that, as this code will fail on various devices, such as Android 4.2+ tablets where the code is running under a secondary account.

Comment: So how can i create a file in the sdcard from C code. Can u give me some idea or some sample.